# Error 404 in www folder

Tags: php, apache2, localhost, lamp

I've this problem in my Apache installation in localhost (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tips:

Clean installation and httpd.conf file is empty (blank)

This command line open a file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

The file have this data:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And i need to move /var/www to my home directory, for example:

```
/home/USER/www/site1

/home/USER/www/site2
```

In advance thank you! :D

Comment: so just do it? DocumentRoot /var/www => /home/USER/www

Comment: and the Directory directive

Comment: I tried, but it did not work, you still receive Error 404

Comment: You did restart Apache after the change, right?

Comment: Only editing this file or any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take backup of configuration file before made any changes.

> sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-bak

Then edit config file:

> sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Replace below entries:

> DocumentRoot /var/www
>
> Directory /var/www/

to

> DocumentRoot /home/USER/www
>
> Directory /home/USER/www

and restart apache

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure that the apache process has access to that directory.  You'll need to `chown` the folder so that `www-data` can access it.

For instance

`sudo chown -R :www-data ~/www`

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved, but, when you have **ERROR 404** problem with phpMyAdmin, paste this code in console `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /home/USER/phpmyadmin`

This is for symbolic link to phpmyadmin.

Working fine.

Thanks.